# How to pass dynamic file location in Form API?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

my requirement is to upload files to specific folders. How can I achieve this by using form api.
How can I modify below code such that upload_location should be dynamic.  Uploaded file should save into the Folder name provided by the user. 
**#submit element is not calling custom_document_submit function.**

```
 $form['folder_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Folder Name'),
  );
  $form['document'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('xml')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#submit' => array('custom_document_submit'),
    );
function custom_document_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $destination = $form_state['values']['folder_name'];
  $validators = array();
  $file = file_save_upload('document', $validators, 'public://'.$destination);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [#submit property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#submit_property) cannot be declare on a managed_file form object...

Instead, you have to add or to modify a submit action on your form (or button).

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_document_submit';
```

If you don't want to modify the submit method of your form, you can also simply add a validator (with the [#validate property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#validate)), witch will modify the '#upload_location' property of your document depending on the folder_name value.

Both, #submit and #validate properties have to be added to the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

define('IMPORT_DIRECTORY_PATH', 'public://import');

$form['folder_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Folder Name'),
  );


  form['document'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Upload .xml'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('xml'),
    ),
    '#process' => array('import_document_element_process'),
  );

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Upload'),
    '#submit' => array('custom_document_submit'),
  );

function custom_document_submit($form, &$form_state){

  // Validate extensions.
    $validators = array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('xml'),
    );
    $file = file_save_upload('document', $validators, FALSE, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

    // If the file passed validation.
    if ($file) {
      // Rename uploaded file to prevent cache from remembering name file.
      $directory = SCHEDULES_IMPORT_DIRECTORY_PATH;
      if (file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS)) {
        $uri = $directory . '/xml_' . $file->uid . '_' . $file->timestamp . '.xml';
        if ($file = file_move($file, $uri)) {
          $form_state['values']['document'] = $file;
        }
        else {
          form_set_error('document', t('The file could not be uploaded.'));
        }
      }
      else {
        form_set_error('document', t('The directory is not writable.'));
      }
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('document', t('The file extension is not correct.'));
    }
    // dpm($form_state['values']['document']);
    // var_dump( $form_state['values']['document']);
}


/**
 * Removing the upload button in managed files.
 */
function import_document_element_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);
  $element['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;

  return $element;
}
```